# What is this library devoted to electrical circuits?

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz, tikz-circuit-lib, circuits

*Hello, what is this library?...*

[image]

Comment: It looks a lot like the examples in the circuitikz manual. What about it makes you think it is not circuitikz?

Comment: Hi and welcome. You can have a look at our [TeX.SX starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: I circuitikz use and can not do arrow current. Also graphic resistance is different.
Sorry not speak english good. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please show the code you have so far.

Comment: Where did you take this picture from? Probably it isn't made with latex.

Comment: Only have picture and want to know what library use?... Sorry not speak english good. Thanks

Comment: I am neither a TikZ nor a circuit expert, but does it have to be exactely this? Would it be ok to be *just alike*?

Comment: I want to know what library use?

Comment: People have said: use `circuitikz`. If you are stuck, post what you have so far i.e. your code.